# Converter returning Segoe MDL2 icon after binding does not work

Tags: xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to bind the PlayerFramework.MediaPlayer.CanPause Property to a Button in my windows 10 universal app. This works using the default font, but when I switch to Segoe MDL2 to get those fancy icons the button shows garbage.

```
<mmppf:MediaPlayer x:Name="mediaElement">

...

<Button Name="btnPlay" 
        Style="{StaticResource transportStyle}"  Content="{Binding CanPause, ElementName=mediaElement, Converter={StaticResource CanPauseToPlayPauseConverter}}"/>
```

This is from the converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        bool canPause = (bool)value;
        if (canPause)
            return @"&#xE769;";
        // "play"
        return "&#xE102;";
    }
```

...and this from the button style:

```
<Style x:Name="transportStyle"  TargetType="Button">
       <!-- <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe MDL2 Assets" />-->
</Style>
```

After disabling the Setter property the button shows the expected value

```
&#xE102;
```

which, directly set as the button content, shows the play symbol.

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

edit: Copying the character from the character table and returning it does work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`&#xE102;` is a unicode character escape sequence in XML (and hence also in XAML). In C# it is written as `\uE102`.

So the converter should return strings (or characters) with proper C# unicode character escape sequences:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    return (bool)value ? "\uE769" : "\uE102";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to return a char not a string:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        bool canPause = (bool)value;
        if (canPause)
            return '\xE769';
        // "play"
        return '\xE102';
    }
```

Comment: "You have to return a char not a string" is not true. The problem is not if it's a string or a char, it's just the way unicode escape sequences are written in C#. While `&#xE102;` is XML (or XAML), it's `\uE102` in C#, regardless if that is in a string or a single character. Your converter may as well return `"\uE102"`. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31976379/1136211).