# Windows 10 symbol rendering issue

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, windows-10

I recently upgraded from Win7 to Win10. I noticed that some symbols are not rendered correctly on the WPF UI.

For e.g. if I have a date-time string displayed with a hyphen between date and time part, the hyphen will be rendered as a box.

`StringFormat='MMM dd, yyyy - hh:mm:ss tt'`

[image]

But if I convert the hyphen to corresponding unicode value, it renders it correctly. 
`StringFormat='MMM dd, yyyy &#x2010; hh:mm:ss tt'`

Any ideas why this occurs ?

---

Now in the case when I directly assign the text value in XAML with unicode characters, it works fine. But if I bind a `string`(with unicode characters) to `Label`, it will render as it is with unicodes. I think it is how the StringToContent converters work.

[image]

Comment: `&#x2010;` is an XML unicode character escape sequence. In code-behind you would have to use a C# escape sequence like `\u2010`. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31976379/1136211).

Comment: Otherwise, why don't you use a simple minus `-` character?

Comment: @Clemens: The whole question is because of the minus character. It isn't getting rendered as hyphen but a box. Thanks for C# unicode suggestion.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/371282/my-windows-7-has-suddenly-stopped-displaying-unicode-symbols